Npm Angular Warning while installing Angular CLI
I am getting npm warnings when I am trying to install CLI via: npm install -g @angular/cli:

C:\Users\myuser>npm install -g @angular/cli@16.2.1
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated read-package-json@6.0.4: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@6.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated are-we-there-yet@3.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated gauge@4.0.4: This package is no longer supported.

added 1 package, changed 271 packages, and audited 273 packages in 44s

39 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\myuser>ng version
"ng" is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

What am i doing wrong? Or how can it be solved? Thanks!
I was expecting to install Angular CLI.

maybe you don't ng installed or have you installed in it and your npm cant find it? if yes you should just add ng to your npm path by doing npm prefix -g ; copy output and then add to \bin or node_modules if you are in a project.
